# Сортировка списков

Tags: java, list, arraylist

> 21. Необходимо из списка чисел составить новый список, состоящий из чисел, которые останутся на своем месте список отсортировать по
>     возрастанию, например:
>
> ```
> { 3, 1, 3, 7, 7, 5, 9, 9, 15, 12, 10 } → { 3, 7, 9, 9, 12 }
> ```
>
> Самый простой вариант – создать дополнительный список из элементов
> переданного списка, новый список отсортировать, а затем сравнивать
> элементы двух списков

Мой код:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> din = new ArrayList<>(5);
        din.add(3);
        din.add(1);
        din.add(3);
        din.add(7);
        din.add(7);
        din.add(5);
        din.add(9);
        din.add(9);
        din.add(15);
        din.add(12);
        din.add(10);
        ArrayList<Integer> din1 = new ArrayList<>(5);
        din1.add(3);
        din1.add(1);
        din1.add(3);
        din1.add(7);
        din1.add(7);
        din1.add(5);
        din1.add(9);
        din1.add(9);
        din1.add(15);
        din1.add(12);
        din1.add(10);
        Collections.sort(din1);
        for(int i = 0; i<=din1.size(); i++){
           if(din.get(i) == din1.get(i)){
               din1.remove(i);
           }
            System.out.print(din1.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Выводит `{1,3,5,7,9,9,10,12} ,а не { 3, 7, 9, 9, 12 }`

Comment: А с чем у вас возникла сложность? :)

Answer (score 1):

Действия:

- Создаете копию списка.
- Сортируете копию
- Проходите одним циклом по индексами обоих списков и сравниваете элементы
- Если элементы совпадают, значит свою позицию они не поменяли

Пример:

```
ArrayList<Integer> dinSorted = new ArrayList<>(din);
Collections.sort(dinSorted);

ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < din.size(); i++) {
    Integer value = din.get(i);

    if (value.equals(dinSorted.get(i))) {
        items.add(value);
    }
}

System.out.println(items); // [3, 7, 9, 9, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

В-нулевых, `i < din1.size()`.

Во-первых, надо проверять не на равенство, а на неравенство.

А во-вторых, надо идти с конца - после первого удаления индексация двух списков рассинхронизируется.